# Are gravitons possible in 2+1 spacetime dimensions?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

Spin-1 massless particles are transverse waves, so they need at least three space-time dimensions to exists. As for gravitons, I think they are still not possible in three dimensions, and to reveal their true nature one needs at least four dimensions; otherwise there would be no way to distinguish a graviton form a vector in such a three dimensional universe. Other argument against it is the fact that there's only (grav.) radiation in four or more dimensions, but I'm looking for a "theorem" more in the context of field theory.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68824/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74307/2451 and links therein.

Comment: If the perturbative field doesn't have any degrees of freedom not determined by $T_{ab}$, as is the case for 2+1 gravity (the Weyl tensor vanishes), what are you even quantizing?

Comment: Is your question essentially if it is (im)possible to write down a theory for a dynamical massless spin-2 field in 2+1 dimensions?

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning for e.g. electromagnetism in 2 dimensions. But indeed for gravity you have no dofs in 3 dimensions: *massless* gravity is famously topological (https://inspirehep.net/literature/21208) but not for the reason you mention.