# Degrees of freedom in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, degrees-of-freedom

A way one counts degrees of freedom(i.e. independent entries of the metric tensor ) in General Relativity is this:
one goes to the linearized version, vacuum solution, and he sees that there are two independent polarizations(e.g. L-R).

1. First: how can I know that the number of degrees of freedom in the linearized case are the same of the general case?
2. Second: I want to know in general how can I interpret physically the degrees of freedom? Or have I to see it for each system under investigation?
3. Third, is there other ways to count degrees of freedom? For example by Killing Vectors?

Comment: This question (v3) is also addressed in e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19342/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/68828/2451) Phys.SE answers.