# Why is general relativity considered to be a gauge theory?

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory

I have studied the first five chapters of Carroll's book (up to the Schwarzschild solution). I see similarities to the Yang-Mill theories such as the covariant derivative to account for curvature in GR which is similar to the covariant derivative to account for local gauge transformations in Yang-Mill theories. I have heard that some consider GR to be a gauge theory, but I do not understand what the redundant degrees of freedom are required to make it gauge theory.

Comment: Related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46324/

Comment: Not knowing the answer myself, I am aware of [this book](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/p781) that you might be interested in...

Comment: @Hunter:  Also, Hehl gave lectures on the above book, that you can watch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_2AjwRl0ho).

Comment: @MurodAbdukhakimov thanks! That does indeed answer my question. This question can be closed.