# Can the covariant derivative of General relativity be obtained from a $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$ transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Is it possible to obtain general relativity as a gauge theory from the general linear group?

The starting point is:

$$
M'=GM
$$

where $M',M,G$ are elements of $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$.

---

I believe the second step is to construct a 'pass-throught' derivative (gauge covariant derivative) such that:

$$
D (GM) = GdM \tag{1}
$$

---

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative#General_relativity, the covariant derivative of general relativity is :

$$
\nabla_j v^I:=\partial_jv^I +\sum_k \Gamma^i_{jk}v^k  \tag{2}
$$

How can I obtain (2) starting from (1)?

Finally, if you look at this answer [To which extent is general relativity a gauge theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46324/to-which-extent-is-general-relativity-a-gauge-theory) it seems to suggest that you can, but then the comment section of this answer seems to show the author backtracking on the claim.

Comment: I don't believe that your 'pass-through' derivative is well defined, since given $G,M, A\in\mathrm{GL_n}$ we have $D(GM)=D(GMAA^{-1})=GdM=GMd(AA^{-1})=GMAd(A^{-1})$. I think you have to get a little more into the weeds and consider the action of the Lorentz group on the spacetime manifold since this action preserves the metric structure.