# Where can I find a reference regarding gauging the $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$ group, and general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory

The following answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/46367/747 provides a derivation of the connection from gauging the general linear group. I am looking for a reference to this derivation.

Comment: I do not have much to add as a separate answer, so I'll just comment here: Look for Frederic Schuller's lectures on the Geometrical Anatomy of theoretical Physics. It is a great lecture series as he starts from scratch (on the foundation of axiomatic set theory) and builds up the idea of gauge theory . You can find the entire course on Youtube : (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic ). In case you are aware of Principal Lie group bundle morphisms, skip to Lec 22 where he introduces Frame bundle to construct gauge theory of GL(n,R)