# Einstein field equations from covariant derivative of a general linear gauge transformation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, differentiation, curvature

A general linear transformation is given by

\begin{align}
  \psi'(x) \to g \psi(x) g^{-1},
\end{align}

The gauge-covariant derivative associated with this transformation is

\begin{align}
 D_\mu \psi=\partial_\mu \psi -[iqA_\mu, \psi].
\end{align}

Finally, the field is given as

\begin{align}
 R_{\mu\nu}= [D_\mu,D_\nu],
\end{align}

where, $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Riemann tensor.

From here, what steps lead me to the Einstein field equation?

Comment: You seem confused about what we mean when we say GR is a gauge theory ($R_{\mu\nu}$ is *not* the Riemann tensor!). See [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/706483/50583) for the differences between GR and Yang-Mills theories.

Answer (score 4):

None. Nothing  of this has anything to do with gravity. Your equation for "R" defines the gauge field curvature $F_{\mu\nu}$, not the Riemann curvature $R_{\alpha \beta\mu\nu}$.

Comment: I am using the general linear group for the gauge.

Comment: You are still not going to get gravity as GR  is not a gauge theory (fibre bundle) in the usual sense. There is a formulation of (non super) suopergravity that  gauges the Poincare group, but each fibre conatins the whole of space, so again it's not a conventional gauge theory.