# What is the relation of differential geometry to General Relativity and Quantum Field Theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, differential-geometry, string-theory, quantum-gravity

We know that Yang Mills Theory forms the basis of the Standard Model of Physics, which describe the interaction of elementary particles at high energies, of course not including gravity. Yang Mills theory (gauge theory) and gravity are described by local invariance.

String theory unifies gauge theory and gravity, what is the relation between gauge theory and gravity?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gravity as a gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71476/)

Comment: @Eletie Thanks for the useful answer