# Gravity as a gauge theory - Cartan-Killing form?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

First, let me state the form of Lagrangian for YM and GR 
\begin{align}
L_{YM} = \alpha  \textrm{tr}(F^2), \qquad L_{GR} = \beta R
\end{align}
I heard, YM is a gauge theory but GR isn't a really gauge theory.  Due to the fact of its Cartan-Killing form of YM is positive, but GR is negative. 
Is it valid approach?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4359/2451 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12461/2451 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46324/2451 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71476/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Why did you state the Lagrangians if you did nothing with it? What do you mean by the "Cartan-Killing form of YM/GR"? The Killing form is a property of a *group*, not of a theory.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I mean, consider GR as $diff(M)$ and YM as $SU(N)$, group theory.

Comment: If you want the correct analogy to the global gauge group $\mathrm{SU}(N)$, you need to take $\mathrm{GL}(N)$, not $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$. And again, the Killing form not being positive is just a group theoretical fact - only compact group manifolds can have a definite Killing form. It's nothing to do with being a gauge theory or not.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Thanks, i think my senior is wrong in some sense and you are right. I understand your point.