# Does gravity have a gauge symmetry group?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gauge-theory

In the Standard Model, U(1) corresponds to the electromagnetic, SU(2) to weak, and SU(3) to strong interactions. I realize that gravity is not a part of the Standard Model. However, sometimes gravity is also viewed as a gauge theory. If so, does it correspond to any particular symmetry group or is this a wrong way of thinking and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gravity as a gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71476/)

Comment: Other possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4359/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12461/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46324/2451 ,  and links therein.

Comment: Also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346793/50583